# Extra characters appear when I parse the json object

Tags: php, ajax

I extracted a list of websites from an external website in an array of strings using PHP and then I used an ajax request to retrieve the list as json encoded array. However when I parse and display the restaurant information, some extra characters appear. This is my php code:

```
 <?php
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
    $restaurantArray=array();
    for($j=1;$j<=4;$j++){
    $original="http://www.visitblagoevgrad.com/restaurantseng.aspx?page=".$j;
    $html=file_get_html($original);
    $title=$html->find('a[class=link1]');
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($title);$i++){
    parse_str( parse_url( $title[$i], PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );
    $link=$my_array_of_vars['id'];
    $id=substr($link, 0,2);
    if ($id[1]=="\"")
        $id=substr($id,0,1);
    $original1="http://www.visitblagoevgrad.com/restaurantdetailseng.aspx?id=".$id;
    //echo $original1."</br>";
    $html1=file_get_html($original1);
    $arr1=$html1->find("span[id=lblHead]");
    $arr2=$html1->find("a[class=link1]");
    $arr3=$arr2[0]->parent()->plaintext;
    $restaurantArray[" ".$arr1[0]]=$arr3;

}
}
echo json_encode($restaurantArray);
```

This is the output after usin jQuery.parseJSON(response) in my html file:
[Description of restaurants+some extra characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB9pa.png)

Comment: Is it neccesary to add an blank space to `$restaurantArray[" ".$arr1[0]]=$arr3;` ?

Comment: Yes, because otherwise, it will produce an error: $arr1[0] is not a valid index.

Comment: The reason you get extra characters in the output is because there are extra characters in the input data, including tabs which are displayed as rectangles. If you want to make that data displayable directly without parsing you will need to filter out unexpected characters like tabs or spaces in unneeded places.

Comment: How can i filter them, since i extract the data from an external website, i don't add them manually? Thanks.

Comment: [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) will allow you to replace the tabs easily. Spaces are way more tricky because in some places they are semantically relevant and in others they are not. A good heuristic might be to remove groups of spaces only when there is more than 2 together.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had been struggling with it for hours.

Comment: Some special characters such as <p> and &nbsp; still remain unparsed and are displayed along with the information. Do you have any suggestion on how to remove them?